W column and max(w) column produce the same results. How to fix?
select season, w, max(w) as [Most wins by a team] 
from [dbo].[Team Summaries] 
where w is not null 
group by season, w
order by season

I am trying to produce how many wins (w) each team would have for each season vs the highest number of wins for that season.

Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results

Certainly don't use single quotes ' to delimit your column alias in SQL Server, its not an official delimiter and the results can be unexpected. Ideally don't use reserved words or characters so no delimiting is necessary but if you have to, then use [] or "" never ''.

Did the answers help you?

You can use the window function variant of max(). See the SELECT - OVER Clause documentation. When used this way, you no longer need the group by. Window functions will gather and aggregate data across multiple result rows of the result set (the "window") as defined by the OVER clause.
Something like:
select
    season,
    team,
    w as wins,
    max(w) OVER(PARTITION BY season) AS [Most wins by a team this season],
    max(w) OVER() AS [Most wins by a team overall] 
from dbo.[Team Summaries] 
where w is not null 
order by season, team

I am assuming that your [Team Summaries] source data has as team column or similar.
Sample results:



season
team
wins
Most wins by a team this season
Most wins by a team overall




2022
Knights
5
6
10


2022
Pawns
2
6
10


2022
Rooks
6
6
10


2023
Knights
8
10
10


2023
Pawns
10
10
10


2023
Rooks
3
10
10



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
